# Serialize a polymorphic F case class using Play Json

Tags: json, scala, spray-json, play-json, higher-kinded-types

I have a situation where I have to have this `case class Config[F[_]](pattern: String, format:F[String])`, because sometimes the format should be present, and use it like `Config[Id]` and sometimes not and make it with `Config[Option]`.
The question is, how is this coping with Play or Spray Json and what are some best practices to serialize / deseralize such a structure.
I use to use this trick few times before, but never forced to serialized until and I wonder how read and write methods should look like. Also, if there are any drawback or penalties, performance wise as well.
Any thoughts? Thanks, folks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if derivation is not made bad, you would be able to make codecs for Config[List] and Config[Option].

In circe it should be like this:

```scala
implicit val configOptionCodec: Codec[Config[Option]] = deriveCodec
implicit val configListCodec: Codec[Config[List]] = deriveCodec
```

This won't give you much performance penalty, just boilerplate penalty. However you can write macro like @JsonCodecsFor(List, Option, Chain).